# What happens if the function of a python thread is completed?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using python thread while I found no method to stop it.

Here is how I use the thread:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, args=()):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__return_value = None
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.func_name = func.__name__

    def run(self):
        self.__return_value = self.func(*self.args)
```

Considering there is no explicit way to stop it, I try to ignore it when it finishes the function to execute.
Will a zombie thread left if I do nothing when it finishes?

Comment: Re, "I try to ignore it when it finishes..." So, how does your other code know when to look at the `__return_value`?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have noticed the problem you mentioned. I have to consider it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the thread pack up after itself and shuts down cleanly.

It is how things in Python try to work, after all.

```
import threading
import time

def worker():
    time.sleep(1)

def main():
    print (threading.active_count())
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    print(threading.active_count())
    time.sleep(2)
    print(threading.active_count())
    return t

main()

t = main()
t.is_alive()
```

Running this snippet in ipython (an interactive prompt which uses some threads for its own purposes) will print

```
4
5
4

False
```